# Vulkan vertex input attribute normalization (conversion)

Tags: vulkan

`glVertexAttribPointer` in OpenGL automatically converts integer attributes to float with the possibility of optional normalization.

Is there a way to tell Vulkan to convert integer input attributes to float ? Or do I have to do this manually in shader ?

Comment: @httpdigest Yes, that seems to be correct. I just figured that out too. Please make your comment an answer, so I can accept it.